# Issue loading 'dplyr' sometimes

Tags: r, dplyr

Sometimes when I try to load dplyr I get the following error:

```
Error in library.dynam(lib, package, package.lib) : 
  shared object ‘dplyr.so’ not found
In addition: Warning message:
S3 methods ‘[.grouped_df’, ‘[.tbl_df’, ‘all.equal.tbl_df’, ‘all.equal.tbl_dt’, ‘anti_join.data.frame’, ‘anti_join.data.table’, ‘anti_join.tbl_df’, ‘anti_join.tbl_sql’, ‘arrange_.data.frame’, ‘arrange_.data.table’, ‘arrange_.grouped_dt’, ‘arrange_.tbl_df’, ‘arrange_.tbl_dt’, ‘arrange_.tbl_sql’, ‘as.data.frame.grouped_df’, ‘as.data.frame.rowwise_df’, ‘as.data.frame.tbl_cube’, ‘as.data.frame.tbl_df’, ‘as.data.frame.tbl_dt’, ‘as.data.frame.tbl_sql’, ‘as.fun_list.character’, ‘as.fun_list.fun_list’, ‘as.tbl.data.frame’, ‘as.tbl.data.table’, ‘as.tbl.tbl’, ‘as.tbl_cube.array’, ‘as.tbl_cube.data.frame’, ‘as.tbl_cube.matrix’, ‘as.tbl_cube.table’, ‘auto_copy.tbl_cube’, ‘auto_copy.tbl_df’, ‘auto_copy.tbl_dt’, ‘auto_copy.tbl_sql’, ‘c.sql’, ‘collapse.data.frame’, ‘collapse.tbl_df’, ‘collapse.tbl_dt’, ‘collapse.tbl_sql’, ‘collect.data.frame’, ‘c [... truncated] 
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘dplyr’
```

Once I restart the R process is will work fine. Is there any reason this is happening sometimes but not other times?

Comment: Bad hard-drive? Bad memory? Make sure your backups are complete.

Comment: How about uninstalling and reinstalling? Sometimes it fixes the mysterious issue.

Comment: I get the same error when installing `dplyr` on a shiny server...

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment because I don't have 50 reputation HOWEVER I did have the same problem and I followed what marbles had suggested.

I am using a Mac and was using Microsoft's checkpoint package and could not load it properly if I had `library(dplyr)` in my R chunk. I removed the dplyr folder from ~/Library/R/3.3/library/dplyr as well as the dplyr folder from ~/.checkpoint/2017-01-01/lib/dplyr then just loaded the libraries and checkpoint seemed to correctly load dplyr.

I was obviously using the checkpoint date of January 1 2017. I also had to create the local .checkpoint folder because it was not automatically created. My document compiles (I haven't tried any serious code in it yet though) so I am assuming it works.